# Composition of homotheties does not look homothetic

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry, homothety

Given an affine space $X$, let us define homotheties $h_1,h_2$ as

$$
h_1(x) = c_1 + \lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}
$$

$$
h_2(x) = c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2x}
$$

for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb R$, $c_1, c_2 \in X$.

The composition $h_2 \circ h_1$ can thus be written as
$$
h_2 \circ h_1(x) = c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2x'}
$$
where $x'=h_1(x)$.

Now, if we consider $\overset\longrightarrow{c_2x'}=\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}$, then
$$
h_2 \circ h_1(x) = c_2 + \lambda_2(\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x})=c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}
$$
This looks like it is only a homothety when $c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}=c_1$, and not a translation since the vector depends on $x$. However, the composition of two homotheties should be either homothetic or a translation.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that:
$$
c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}=
c_3 +\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_3x},
\quad\hbox{where}\quad
c_3=c_2-{\lambda_2\over\lambda_2\lambda_1-1}\overset\longrightarrow{c_1c_2}.
$$
I found the center $c_3$ of the resulting homothety as the solution of the equation $h_2 \circ h_1(x)=x$.

Of course this doesn't work if $\lambda_2\lambda_1=1$. In that case the result is just a translation:
$$
h_2 \circ h_1(x)=c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}=
x+(\lambda_2-1)\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}.
$$

Comment: Not quite sure I see why...

Comment: What exactly you don't see? If you substitute $c_3$ in $c_3 +\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_3x}$ with $c_3=c_2-{\lambda_2\over\lambda_2\lambda_1}\overset\longrightarrow{c_1c_2}$ you get exactly $c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}$.

Comment: See also my edited answer.

Comment: $c_3=c_2-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_2\lambda_1}\overset\longrightarrow{c_1c_2}=c_2-\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\overset\longrightarrow{c_1c_2}$ does not depend on $\lambda_2$, which seems odd. Also, doesn't an example with $\lambda_1 \approx 1$, $\lambda_2=1/2$ contradict your proposal? I checked graphically, although I might of course have made a mistake.

Comment: Nothing allows you, from $h_2 \circ h_1(x) = c_2 + \lambda_2(\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x})=c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}+\lambda_2\lambda_1\overset\longrightarrow{c_1x}$ to deduce that $c_2 + \lambda_2\overset\longrightarrow{c_2c_1}=c_1$.

Comment: Sorry: I realized just now that I made a typo: it should be $$c_3=c_2-{\lambda_2\over\lambda_2\lambda_1-1}\overset\longrightarrow{c_1c_2}$$

Comment: Now I corrected the formula and added the case $\lambda_2\lambda_1=1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know. What I was saying was that that condition looked as thoughit might be necessary for the composition to be a homothety, which I know can not be true because homotheties and translations constitute a group. I was therefore asking where my mistake was, if in that assumption or elsewhere in the derivation.

Comment: @Aretino Thanks! I was going crazy trying to make the first thing fit.